# ImportError: cannot import name pywrap_dlopen_global_flags

Tags: tensorflow, virtualenv, protocol-buffers, keras-rl

I get the following error when trying to use tensorflow (version - newest as of date of posting) on Hardware - MacBookPro CPU with OS - Dual Boot Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
in a virtualenv —no-site-packages with Keras and keras-rl and python 2.7.

```
...
 Using TensorFlow backend.
2018-02-15 18:55:01,909 [Thread-46   ] [hbp_nrp_cles] [CRITICAL]  Unhandled exception of type <type 'exceptions.RuntimeError'>: module compiled against API version 0xb but this version of numpy is 0xa
2018-02-15 18:55:01,909 [Thread-46   ] [hbp_nrp_cles] [ERROR]  None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/akshay/.opt/kerasrl_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 37, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_dlopen_global_flags
ImportError: cannot import name pywrap_dlopen_global_flags
2018-02-15 18:55:01,910 [Thread-46   ] [hbp_nrp_cles] [CRITICAL]  Unhandled exception of type <type 'exceptions.RuntimeError'>: module compiled against API version 0xb but this version of numpy is 0xa
2018-02-15 18:55:01,910 [Thread-46   ] [hbp_nrp_cles] [ERROR]  None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/akshay/.opt/kerasrl_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 37, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_dlopen_global_flags
ImportError: cannot import name pywrap_dlopen_global_flags
[libprotobuf FATAL external/protobuf_archive/src/google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:68] This program requires version 3.5.0 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, but the installed version is 3.4.0.  Please update your library.  If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library.  (Version verification failed in "google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.cc".)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'google::protobuf::FatalException'

...
```

I used

```
site.addsitedir(os.path.expanduser('path/to/tensorflow_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages'))
```

to import keras-rl modules while working in another environment

What does this ImportError mean? I have checked the code in the file pwrap_tensorflow.py and don’t understand the comment above the exception.

```
...
try:
  # This import is expected to fail if there is an explicit shared object
  # dependency (with_framework_lib=true), since we do not need RTLD_GLOBAL.
  from tensorflow.python import pywrap_dlopen_global_flags
  _use_dlopen_global_flags = True
except ImportError:
  _use_dlopen_global_flags = False
...
```

I am also getting a protobuf issue.  The protobuf version in the venv is 3.5.1